# Image views won't align correctly with constraints in collection view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uiimage

I have a collection view set up and am trying to add some images to it.  The images have appeared to the view, but with the constraints I have, they won't center both x and y.
Here is the code:

```
class MenuCell: BaseCell {

let imageView: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.image =  UIImage(named: "icons8-person-24")
    return iv
}()

override func setupViews() {
    super.setupViews()

    addSubview(imageView)
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0(28)]|", views: imageView)
    addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|[v0(28)]|", views: imageView)
    addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerX, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerY, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify `H:` and `V:` visual layout constraints that constraint to border.

Change this:

```
addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0(28)]|", views: imageView)
addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|[v0(28)]|", views: imageView)
```

To this:

```
addConstraintsWithFormat("H:[v0(28)]", views: imageView)
addConstraintsWithFormat("V:[v0(28)]", views: imageView)
```